# Why can I parse an 8 digit hex into a Long, and convert it to an Integer, but not parse as an Integer directly?

Tags: java, parsing, integer, long-integer

I am trying to use `ColorDrawable(int color)`. This class only has an `int` constructor.
Normally, you can do something like this:

```
ColorDrawable(0xFF8E8F8A)
```

But since I am getting my color as a String (6 hex digits, no alpha), I have to do this:

```
Long color = Long.parseLong("FF"+hexColorString, 16); // hexColorString like "8E8F8A"
ColorDrawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(color.intValue());
```

Why doesn't `Integer.parseInt("FF"+hexColorString, 16)` just return me a negative (effectively unsigned) int, instead of throwing a `NumberFormatException`?

EDIT: A more succinct version of my question:

Why don't `Long.parseLong("FF"+hexColorString, 16).intValue()` and `Integer.parseInt("FF"+hexColorString, 16)` return the same value? The former works, but the latter gives me an Exception.

EDIT: I wasn't getting the correct color anyway, so I switched to the following method:

```
ColorDrawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF"+hexColorString));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `0xFF8E8F8A` is `> Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Since no overflow or underflow throws `Exception`s by design, it will interpret your value as `Integer.MIN_VALUE` instead, because `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` shifts to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

So, `Long.intValue` will **convert** the value to `int`, which, with a given value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE + x` where `x > 0`, will shift from `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, i.e. `Integer.MIN_VALUE + x`.

However, from `Integer` javadoc:

> An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the
>   following situations occurs:
>
> The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.  [...] The
>   value represented by the string is not a value of type int.

A value of `0xFF8E8F8A` is not of type `int`, hence the `NumberFormatException`.

As a side-note, I'm pretty sure `ColorDrawable` constructor takes an `int` because it takes an id instead of a numerical representation of your color, but to be honest the documentation isn't quite clear on that.

See `R.color` documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html).

**Final note** - credit goes to [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2301185/blufenix) on this one.

You can use `new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(yourHexString))` for a more convenient approach.

Comment: I think understand that part, but why don't `Long.parseLong("FF"+hexColorString, 16).intValue()` and `Integer.parseInt("FF"+hexColorString, 16)` return the same value? The former works, but the latter gives me an Exception.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand. Now I'm concerned that I'm not getting the correct color with my current method.

Comment: @BLuFeNiX just edited my answer. I'm pretty sure `ColorDrawable` takes an id, not a color representation (hence the `int` constructor parameter). Not very clear in the docs and I haven't touched Android for a few months to be honest :)

Comment: Thanks, I am now using `ColorDrawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF"+hexColorString));`, which seems to be working just fine. Problem solved!

Comment: Its so unintuitive because parseInt() has different semantics than the java language with regards to hexadecimal notation (0x87654321 is perfectly fine as a literal in code, but not as input for parseInt)

Comment: @BLuFeNiX cool! Added your findings to my answer crediting you.

Answer (score 1):

Because `0xFF8E8F8A` is outside of integer range. I.e. `0xFF8E8F8A` == `4287532938`, and it is bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Assumption that `0xFF8E8F8A` equals to `-7434358` (the value you get when parsing via Long) is not correct, because you can parse negative hex values:

```
Integer.parseInt("-717076", 16);
```

So `-0x717076` equals to `-7434358` and unsigned representation of it is `0xFF8E8F8A`.